# Sass change detected but style.css only overwritten every 5th - 7th time I save

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I am using Sass and Ruby (newest version) on a Windows 7 64-bit machine, and I am working on a shared folder on my home server. (But, I have to admit the problem itself occurs on the server as well, since I tried to install Ruby and `-watch` the files on the server directly).

The problem is as follows: if I save for the first time, a change is detected and my `style.css` gets overwritten directly. After that, I always need to save up to 7 times in order to get the `style.css` overwritten. Every time, there is a change detected but nothing is compiled. Here's a screen:

```
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
overwrite style.css
>>> Change detected to: E:/Websites/xxx/wp-content/themes/xxx/sass/default-styles.sass
>>> Change detected to: E:/Websites/xxx/wp-content/themes/xxx/sass/default-styles.sass
>>> Change detected to: E:/Websites/xxx/wp-content/themes/xxx/sass/default-styles.sass
>>> Change detected to: E:/Websites/xxx/wp-content/themes/xxx/sass/default-styles.sass
>>> Change detected to: E:/Websites/xxx/wp-content/themes/xxx/sass/default-styles.sass
>>> Change detected to: E:/Websites/xxx/wp-content/themes/xxx/sass/default-styles.sass
>>> Change detected to: E:/Websites/xxx/wp-content/themes/xxx/sass/default-styles.sass
overwrite style.css
```

Here is glance at my `base.sass`, which imports all the partials:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import variables

// Default HTML Formatting
@import default-styles

// Grid
@import grid

// Header and Menus
@import header

// Blog
@import blog
```

Has anyone had a similar issue on Windows?

Comment: Ok got it myself, it was the Servertime. Looks like i was ahead some seconds with my Client PC so the file didnt got updated. Maybe i should sync the time with the windows server.

Comment: server time solved it for me. I am using vagrant so doing a `vagrant reload` took care of the issue.

Comment: Nice, could you add your answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered in the comments. The issue was caused by server-client time differences, so that the server wouldn't initiate the update until the timestamp exceeded the time difference.

I am posting this answer so that the question will be correctly marked as answered.